# Query with $elemMatch inside $cond

Tags: mongodb

The following query does not seem to work (both conditions are set to same to make sure it returns the same thing whether true or false). Is it not possible to mix $elemmatch and $cond ?

```
{'offers':
           {
             $cond: [
               { $ne: ['offers', 'a'] },
               {$elemMatch: {_id: id, 'status': 'A' }},
               {$elemMatch: {_id: id, 'status': 'A' }}
             ]
           }
         },
```

This works fine:

```
{'offers': {$elemMatch: {_id: id, 'status': 'A' }}}
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to do? The syntax here is of course incorrect for everything you have coded and not just the `$elemMatch`, so it's difficult to tell what you actually want to achieve. You seem to be asking something along the lines of providing a condition to determine what content appears in the `"offers"`` property ( presumably an array )  in the result document. Also `{ $ne: ['offers', 'a'] }` makes no sense, because those are just two strings comparing and will never be equal. You probably mean `{ $ne: ['$offers', 'a'] }` or `{ $ne: ['$offers', '$a'] }`, but it's really unclear.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for your reply. Let me clarify. ['offers', 'a'] is always false,  $ne: ['offers', 'a'] should be always true, so the first condition should always be returned. So the first query should be equivalent to the second one. But the first one returns nothing, though the second one works. So that's my question : why is the first one not working ? Im inquiring about the structure of the query mixing $cond and $elemMatch.

Comment: You are completely missing the point and have not clarified anything. What do you think you mean by "query"? [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) is an aggregation pipeline operator and **cannot** be used in a `.find()` query. The statememt `$ne: ['offers', 'a']` makes no sense because you are simply comparing two strings which are not equal. You may as well be asking `$ne: [true,false]` and again it would make absolutely no sense. So the overall question makes no sense.